# virtuemart invoice calculate tax

Tags: php, joomla, virtuemart, invoice

Im using virtuemart for a webshop but the owner of the website wants to use tax on the invoice only
She doesnt want to fill them in on every article, she wants them to be visible and calculated on the incoice

The code that calculates the total price is:

```
$this->currency->priceDisplay($this->orderDetails['details']['BT']->order_total, $this->currency);
```

This displays it as for example:
€ 8,45

How can I calculate this into a 21% of that amount?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help.

```
$this->currency->priceDisplay($this->orderDetails['details']['BT']->order_total * 1.21, $this->currency);
```

Comment: `code $this->currency->priceDisplay($this->orderDetails['details']['BT']->order_total * 0.21, $this->currency);` did the trick! 

I was making it so much more difficult than it actually was
Thank you so much!